# How to animate UIPageViewController transition

Tags: ios, animation, uipageviewcontroller, icarousel

I want to animate transition between `UIViewControllers` in `UIPageViewController` like Cylinder in [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)
How to do this?